# Windows Phone Appcelerator, Tab title

Tags: windows, tabs, windows-phone, appcelerator

I am trying to develop a simple app for Windows Phone with Appcelerator.
In this app, I have 6 tabs with different window. 
My problem is that the title of these tabs is too big. 
I have tryed to insert a label for title but it's not working.
Here the code:

var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ 
    title:'Home', 
    window:win1
});

I developed this App in the Classic mode of Appcelerator.

My problem is about the fontSize of the Title. I don't know how to change it. Do you have any idea? I have noticed that if I compile for Windows Store the size is ok, but, if I compile for Windows Phone is too big.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the above code is the one you want to tell about the big title, as I don't see Home as big title. Still you can do one thing that if suppose any of your app tab's title is large like this: **'This is Window One'**, then you can add a newline character into it. Like below:

```
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ title:'This is\nHome Window', window:win1 });
```